# How can I clear the canvas using one click in processing?

Tags: processing

I was trying to make a very simple game but I'm having trouble with mouse events. I want to only click once and the whole canvas will be cleared but what happen is it keeps on coming back to its original canvas if I'm not clicking anymore.

```java
if((mouseX >= 100) && (mouseX <= 235) &&
   (mouseY >= 490) && (mouseY <= 540) &&
   (mousePressed))
{
  clear ();
  slide1 ();
}
```

This is the second tab:

```java
void slide1()
{
  clear ();
  background (30);`enter code here`
  slide1 = loadImage ("slide1.jpg");
  image (slide1,100,0,400,300);
}
```

Comment: @home check the Processing tag info

Comment: @JonathanRaeCrisanto How is `clear()` implemented and what happens in draw() ?

Comment: @georgeprofenza: ups: I did not realize that this tag is about a language...

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing a complete, working example, it is difficult to tell for certain. However, it seems likely that you have confused `clear()` and `background()`. The easiest way to wipe the screen is by calling `background()` -- for example at the beginning of every draw() frame.

From the [Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/):

> [clear()](https://processing.org/reference/clear_.html): "Clears the pixels within a buffer. This function only works on PGraphics objects"
>
> [background()](https://processing.org/reference/background_.html): "This function is typically used within draw() to clear the display window at the beginning of each frame, but it can be used inside setup() to set the background on the first frame of animation or if the backgound need only be set once."

e.g. (based on your code):

```
PImage slide1;
void setup(){
  size(512,512);
  slide1 = loadImage ("https://processing.org/img/processing3-logo.png");
}
void draw(){
  background (30); // clear screen every frame
  if(mousePressed) { // show image whenever mouse is down
    image (slide1,0,0);
  }
}
```

This always clears the canvas.

Alternately, if you only want to wipe the canvas on a click, don't call background each draw -- instead, call background only on mousePressed. However, in your case (showing an image) it looks like you might also want to wipe again on mouseReleased (so that the image disappears). You may wish to use the built-in `mousePressed()` and `mouseReleased()` Processing functions for this and call background in each one.

I don't think this is what you actually want, but: the actual answer to the title question ("How can I clear the canvas using one click in processing?") is:

```
void draw(){
 line(mouseX,mouseY,pmouseX,pmouseY);
}
void mouseClicked(){
  background(192);
}
```